# Highcharts setData not working when using same array reference

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

So I have en array with some data. I use the `setData` method to set the data on my series like so:

```
chartInstance.series[0].setData(chartData);
```

This works fine the first time, but let's say I change some of the data in `chartData` and want to apply it to my highchart. The next time I call the `setData()` method like above, it doesn't work for me, as in I don't see that changes applied to my chart. However, it works if I do it like this, with `slice()`:

```
chartInstance.series[0].setData(chartData.slice());
```

I was just wondering if this is expected behavior and if so why it works like that? Thanks.

Comment: can you add live example

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's expected behavior.

Here's the explanation from the **API**:

> The new data array is passed by reference (except in case of
>   updatePoints), and may later be **mutated** when updating the chart data.

**Source:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData

So cloning your data (e.g. by using `slice()`) before passing it to `setData` is a good practice.